# Centered masonry layout with percentage widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am trying to implement [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) to my website.

What I am aiming for is for a grid which is centered in the page.

This is easy just by applying a `margin:0 auto;` property.

I then want the items inside to be both responsive (so a percentage width) and centered within the grid (not with no space on the left and a white gap on the right).

Masonry deals with these aspects separately with element sizing and fitWidth respectively. However, it does specify you cannot use them together.

I was wondering if you know of a a way to get these two things together. Either by code or by using an alternative masonry script.

Cheers!